# Are as and while interchangeable in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-meaning

The taxi driver waits as/while Troy loads his luggage in(to) the trunk.

- Is **as** and **while** interchangeable here?
- Should it be **in** or **into**?
- Would you assume from the sentence that it's his own luggage Troy is loading in(to) the trunk?

Answer (score 1):

1. Are "as" and "while" interchangeable here? Yes. Both words have several meanings, but they both can have the meaning of "at the same time".
2. "In" or "into"? "Into" is better. He is moving the luggage from outside the trunk to inside the trunk. It is moving from one place to another, so "in ... to", "into".

"In" would be acceptable here, but in other contexts it could be ambiguous. For example, if I said, "Bob is moving his clothes in the closet", that could mean that he is moving his clothes from someplace that is not the closet to the closet, but most readers would take that to mean that he is re-arranging clothes that are already in the closet to other places in the closet.

3. His own luggage? Yes, you say "his luggage". If you wrote, "... while Troy loads THE luggage", then it could be his own or someone else's. I'd probably guess that it was the luggage of everyone involved: his, his wife's, and his kids', or his and his friends', or whoever is going on this trip.